# SQL view: How do I create a view to get the top 5 highest values for five different categories?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `products` with `prices` and `colours` columns.  I need a view to get the top five most expensive products for each colour.
 How would I do that?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

this will do :

```
 select * from (select a.*,rank() over (partition by colour order by price desc) rk  from 
 tableaname a) where rk<6;
```

rather this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS    select * from (select a.*,rank() over (partition 
by colour order by price desc) rk  from 
tableaname a) where rk<6;
```